# is it possible to customize shortcode in theme -or- make new shortcode combining two shortcodes

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, gravity-forms-plugin, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm sorry if i asking stupid question because as i not code /php expert ?

I usering gravityview to filter and display gravity from values.

> [gravityview id="111" search_field="11" search_value="xyzes"]

Now I want to change search_value dynamically AS "current logged in user"

So I trying making new SHORTCODE but not good working or not good idea

```
add_shortcode( 'customcode' , 'wp_get_current_user_func' );

function wp_get_current_user_func( $atts ) { 
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    return do_shortcode('[gravityview id="1111" search_field="16" search_value="$current_user = wp_get_current_user();"]');
}
```

MY Request please suggest me what right code or is there any way in backend I able to do as altering theme file?

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close enough. Here is how you should do it:

```
add_shortcode( 'customcode' , 'wp_get_current_user_func' );

function wp_get_current_user_func( $atts ) { 
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$user_login = $current_user->user_login;
//return do_shortcode('[gravityview id="1111" search_field="16" search_value=".$user_login."]');
$shortcode = sprintf(
'[gravityview id="%1$s" search_field="%2$s" search_value="%3$s"]',
"1111",
"16",
$user_login
);
echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
}
```

You were missing to retrieve `$current_user->user_login` from function `wp_get_current_user()`

```
$user_login = $current_user->user_login;
```

You can also print out the other values as in this example:

```
<?php
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    /**
     * @example Safe usage: $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
     * if ( !($current_user instanceof WP_User) )
     *     return;
     */
    echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . '<br />';
    echo 'User email: ' . $current_user->user_email . '<br />';
    echo 'User first name: ' . $current_user->user_firstname . '<br />';
    echo 'User last name: ' . $current_user->user_lastname . '<br />';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . '<br />';
    echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . '<br />';
?>
```

Comment: Hello MR Jack I'm sorry for previous doubt but in after check all and put code as you suggested it working now no error but not pulling data in debug i found ........  Array
(
    [field_filters] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => 16
                    [value] => .$user_login.
                    [operator] => contains
                )

            [mode] => all
        )

)

Comment: Maybe you need to remove the the dots like this instead `$user_login` instead of `.$user_login.`

Comment: hi it still same 
                            [key] => 16
                            [value] => $user_login
                            [operator] => contains

Comment: OK! Let me write it using sprintf

Comment: Try this now: `$shortcode = sprintf(
    '[gravityview id="%1$s" search_field="%2$s" search_value="%3$s"]',
    "1111",
    "16",
    $user_login
);
echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );`

Comment: Wow work very smoothly amazing....Thanks you so much for your kind help ....Jack is it okay if I write your detail as shortcode credit

Comment: LOL sure no problem friend ^^

Comment: okay Again Thank you so much for your kind help .I stuck with this since yesterday